# USSD requests on Phonegap

Tags: cordova, ussd

I'm developping an application with phonegap that will use USSD requests to communicate with the MNO. I couldn't find anything. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: were you able to achieve this?